# Verilog RTL: Writing Digital data into predefined memory "address"

Tags: verilog, register-transfer-level

I have [8:0] digital data inputs. I want to pre-define these values and store them with a unique address so I can access them later in my logic by just calling their address value.

Not entirely sure, I was doing something like this (Also, this is for Verilog RTL (Syntheisizable):

```
reg array[8:0];
array[8] = 9'b000000000;
array[7] = 9'b000000001;
array[6] = 9'b000000010;
array[5] = 9'b000000011;
array[4] = 9'b000000100;
array[3] = 9'b000000101;
array[2] = 9'b000000111;
array[1] = 9'b000001000;
array[0] = 9'b000000000;
```

I'm not sure, this is just something that was on top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If youre looking to create a LUT (which is basically want you are suggesting), you are on the right track:

```
reg [8:0] lut [8:0]; // Its an array of 9 elements (0 through 8 after the variable name), each of which is 9 bits wide (before the variable name)
assign lut[8] = 9'b000000000; // If there is a pattern to the array, use generate statement and loops to initialize it, Im just doing it one-by-one here
assign lut[7] = 9'b000000001;
assign lut[6] = 9'b000000010;
assign lut[5] = 9'b000000011;
assign lut[4] = 9'b000000100;
assign lut[3] = 9'b000000101;
assign lut[2] = 9'b000000111;
assign lut[1] = 9'b000001000;
assign lut[0] = 9'b000000000;
```